# Hyperlink in R document

Tags: r, rd

I am writing an R document (Rd) for functions. In markdown, we can create a hyperlink by `[google](https://www.google.com)`. How can I replicate this in R document?

It seems that `\link{...}` can only create a link, which is different from what I am looking for.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `link{}` macro is to link to other documentation pages.

You can use the `\href{}{}` macro to include a link to another webpage, where the text displayed is *not* the link.

Example:

```
\href{http://stackoverflow.com/}{Stack Overflow}
```

In addition to the official R documentation for package development, you can also read the ["Object Documentation" section](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html)  of Hadley's "R Packages" book.

Comment: I would add that for CRAN submission, all links have to work, so the \samp{} notation can be used for links that are not real or that may involve, e.g., login screen redirects.